# What does the notation 'star with some group beneath it' means?

Tags: definition

My thesis promotor sent me [this](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Ebogopolski/Artikel/2000.pdf) text. It talks about automorphism of free groups. On the first page, the following is written:

> Let $\operatorname{Aut}(F_2) \to \operatorname{GL}_2(Z)$ be the homomorphism induced by the abelianization of $F_2$ (the free group of rank 2). It is known that the group of inner automorphisms $\operatorname{Inn}(F_2)$ is the kernel of this map and that
> $$\operatorname{GL}_2(Z) \cong D_4 \underset{D_2}{*} D_6...$$

(the $D_2$ is placed immediately below the star, the star being at the position where one normally places the multiplication sign, didn't know how to fix this. If anyone does, feel free to edit)

What does this strange notation mean?

Comment: amalgamated free product of groups.

Comment: @Randall: could you make this an answer? This way, I can accept it and this question gets closed. + seems I still have some work to do before I can make any sense about that first page :D

Comment: Sure, if you wish.

Comment: I have modified you expression. I think it is what you wanted.

Comment: No, it's usually off to the side as the OP posted, much in the same spirits as $\otimes_R$ for tensor products.

Comment: @mfl: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Randall: I never saw it before, so I am not sure what is customary in this case.

Comment: @Randall In the paper it is used that notation. I don't know the reason.

Comment: Eh, either way.  The notation's not a big deal; understanding the construction is hard enough as is.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard notation for the amalgamated product, a pushout of sorts.

Edit:  I think it's called the amalgamated product, without the adjective free (because it is not actually "free").